Springboot App failing after deployment on Azure App Service
I have springboot app which server react app, on local it is working file but when i deployed this on azure web app with runtime as java 17. It is showing HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request.
What can be the issue.
Note: Springboot app server static react app

If possible, Share your code or github repo?

https://github.com/sanjayprasadF5/springwithreact
here is the github repo

Have you checked,your frontend is not deployed to the github repository.

Are you only deploying your backed to azure web apps?

https://github.com/sanjayprasadF5/ReactAndSpringBoot
can you check this repo

this is updated repo

I tried your code, deployed it to the Azure App Service, and it was successfully deployed without any errors.
First, I built the frontend using the command below to generate the production files. This placed the built React files into the backend/src/main/resources/static directory.
npm install
npm run build


Then, I built the backend using the command below:
mvn clean install


After successfully building the frontend and backend, I deployed the app to an Azure web app, which uses a Linux operating system and Java 17 SE runtime stack.
For deployment, I clicked on the VS Code Azure extension, then clicked on my Azure web app and selected Deploy to Web App. Afterward, I chose the Browse option and located the file backend->target->backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT as shown below.


Azure web App Service Output:


Hi Thanks for reply
I m able to deploy so
only thing is in the target folder i m not able to see the backed-0.0.1- Snapshot.jar
So i directly deploy entire folder it worked for me
now the issue is I want default authentication enable for this
so i added Identity provider in the WebApp from that it stop workingi
Do you have any idea how to implement authentication here for my project

@SanjayPrasad Glad your App is working. For Authentication you need to Add Identity platform to your Web App .
